# MVC3 @html.radiobuttonfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radiobuttonfor

Here is my class :

```
public class QuestionClass 

{ 

    public static FeedbackDatabaseDataContext context = new FeedbackDatabaseDataContext(); 

        public class Tabelfields : Question 
        { 
            //public int QuestionID { get; set; } 
            //public string Email { get; set; } 
            //public string QuestionName { get; set; } 
            //public string Option1 { get; set; } 
            //public string Option2 { get; set; } 
            //public string Option3 { get; set; } 
            //public string Option4 { get; set; } 
             public string SelectedOption { get; set; } 
        } 


        public static List<Question> getallQuestion(string email) 
        { 
            var list = (from q in context.Questions where q.Email==@email select     q).ToList(); 

            return list.ToList();  
        } 
}
```

My view :

```
@model IEnumerable SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass.Tabelfields


<p> Question</p> 


     @foreach (var item in Model) 
     { 
         using (Html.BeginForm("Question", "home", new {email=item.Email,item})) 
         {    

             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName) 

             <br /><br />    
             if (item.Option1 != "") 
             { 
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option1, item)                 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option1) 
                        <br /><br />                 
             } 

             if (item.Option2 != "") 
             { 
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SelectedOption, item.Option2)               
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option2) 
                        <br /><br /> 
             } 

             if (item.Option3 != "") 
             {            
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option3)               
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option3) 
                        <br /><br /> 
             } 


             if (item.Option4 != "") 
             { 
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option4)              
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Option4)  
                        <br /><br />      
             } 
             i = (Int16)i + 1; 


             if (Model.Count() == i) 
             { 
                    <input name="btnsumbit" type="submit" value="Submit Feedback"  
                    style="font-family:Segoe UI Light;font-size:medium;"/> 
             } 
         } 
     }
```

Here Is my controller

```
  public ActionResult Question(string email)

        {              
             return View(QuestionClass.getallQuestion(email)); 
        } 

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Question")] 
        public void Question(string Email,List<QuestionClass.Tabelfields> q) 
        { 
        }
```

In class i.e. "Tabelfields"  I create new property i.e. SelectedOption. I inherite the base class i.e. Question. Where Question is a table in Sql server Database.

I create  strongely type view by using this

```
@model IEnumerable SQLOperation.Models.Question
```

If I change strongely type view as

```
 @model IEnumerable SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass.Tabelfields
```

I get this error

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SQLOperation.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass+Tabelfields]'."

Why should I get this error and how can I solve this ?

Thank you,

ajay

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
  @model IEnumerable SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass.Tabelfields
```

to this:

```
  @model List<SQLOperation.Models.Question>
```

That should fix the error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for rply
I get same error when I use List<SQLOperation.Models.QuestionClass.Tabelfields>

Comment: public static List<Question> getallQuestion(string email) 
{ 
 var list = (from q in context.Questions where q.Email==@email     select     q).ToList(); 

  return list.ToList();  
} 

This code return the List of question from Question table present in SQL server database

Comment: Yes sorry i read it wrong. You are basically passing it a list of Questions. I have edited it above.

Comment: How can I access Tabelfields property i.e. Selectedoption in view??
If I write   @model List<SQLOperation.Models.Question>
I can't access Selectedoption Property in View.
This property is in Tablefield class

Comment: No. this property is in TableFields Class not in Question table.

Comment: hello Gaz Winter
I solve this problem using this
IList<QuestionClass.Tabelfields> viewmodel = new List<QuestionClass.Tabelfields>();
var q = QuestionClass.getallQuestion(email).AsEnumerable();
foreach (SQLOperation.Models.Question item in q)
{
QuestionClass.Tabelfields viewItem = new QuestionClass.Tabelfields();
viewItem.Email = item.Email;
viewItem.QuestionID = item.QuestionID;
viewItem.QuestionName = item.QuestionName;
viewItem.Option1 = item.Option1;
viewItem.Option2 = item.Option2;
viewmodel.Add(viewItem);
}
return View(viewmodel);

Comment: thank you for help.
But now how can I get that selected radiobutton and it's value to controller??

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use some jQuery and a hidden field that you can bind back to the model on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getallQuestion in model to this

```
public static IEnumerable<Question> getallQuestion(string email) 
        { 
            var list = (from q in context.Questions where q.Email==@email select     q).ToList(); 

            return list.AsEnumerable();  //just remove `ToList()` and place `AsEnumerable()`.
        }
```

Try this. This should work for you.