# How to get the value of the row that has been checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model that contain a list of category, the categories are displayed using a table on a web page, I want to add a check box to each roll so that I can select multiple role and delete them all at once, I could do that using Knockout, but I want to do it without using Knockout. How do I go about getting the row value especially the ID column for row that are checked, I tried following the answer gave here [Getting values of check-box from formcollection in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544444/getting-values-of-check-box-from-formcollection-in-asp-net-mvc) but it is not working. Any Ideas Thanks.

Below is a sample code for my model

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Category unique identification
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the category
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Can't be left empty")]
    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "An Error has occured, check your input and try agian")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Below is the code for my view model

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public CategoryViewModel(UnitOfWork _unitofWork)
    {
        CategoryList = _unitofWork.CategoryRepo.GetAll().ToDictionary(v => v, v => IsSelected);
    }

    public IDictionary<Category, bool> CategoryList { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSelected {get; private set; }
}
```

for my view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 8px;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" />
            </th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
       {
           <tr class="odd gradeX">
              <td>
                  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected, item.value)
              </td>
              <td>@item.ID</td>
              <td>@item.Name</td>
           </tr>
       }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my controller action

```
public ActionResult DeleteCat(string[] IsSelected)
```

For example if there are 3 row and none is checked the `IsSelected` parameter of the Action is populated with just the value of false representing each role, but if one row is checked the `IsSelected` parameter is populated with both the value of true and false for that row. How do I get just true for any selected row instead of getting true and false?

Comment: Can you add some code and more details?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us anything.  You need to tell us exactly what you did, with code examples, and explain how it's not working if you want an answer.

Comment: When one checked others not, how many items in string[] IsSelected? and what's the values?

Comment: 4 items are in the string[] IsSelected and the values are true, false, false, false.

Comment: Can you add an output of the HTML generated by your Razor view file to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CategoryList.Length, i++)
{
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CategoryList[i].ID)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CategoryList[i].IsSelected)
        </td>
        <td>@item.ID</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
 }
```